# PHP in_array function does not work properly

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code that tries to do selection on every new element to put into an array (`$desArray`). It is hoped to not put an element that has the same value as one of the existing elements in the array.

The checking job is supposed to be done by `in_array` function, which checks if there already is the same title in `$rss_array`. So the `array_push` will only be done with the unique ones.

```
<?php

/* GOOGLE */

function cURL_google($url, $ref, $p) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
if ($p) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
}
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($result) {
    return $result;
} else {
    return '';
}
}

if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
$keyword_google = $_GET['keyword'];
} else {
echo 'Wrong!';
}

$cseNumber = 'AAAAA';
$key = 'AAAAAP';
$rss_array = array();
$desArray = array();

function _json_decode($file) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $file = stripslashes($file);
    }
    return json_decode($file);
}
$file = cURL_google('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' . $key . '&cx=' .             $cseNumber . '&q=' . $keyword_google . '&siteSearchFilter=i&alt=json&start=1&num=3', 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' . $key . '&cx=' . $cseNumber . '&q=' . $keyword_google . '&siteSearchFilter=i&alt=json&start=1&num=3', null); // . removed from here
$feed = _json_decode($file, true);
foreach ($feed->items as $item) {
$rss_item = array(
    'kind' => $item->kind,
    'Title' => $item->title,
    'Url' => $item->link,
    'Description' => $item->snippet,
    'formattedUrl' => $item->formattedUrl,
);
array_push($desArray, $item->snippet);
array_push($rss_array, $rss_item);
}

/* BING */
if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
$rawkeyword = '%27' . $_GET['keyword'] . '%27';
$keyword = str_replace(' ', '%27', $rawkeyword);
//echo $keyword . '<br>';
} else {
echo 'Wrong!';
}

$key_bing = 'AAAAAA'; 
$root = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/';
$search = $root . 'Web?';
$req = $search . 'Query=' . $keyword . '&$top=3&$format=json';

$ch = curl_init($req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key . ":" . $key_bing);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($resp);

foreach ($json->d->results as $item) {
$rss_item = array(
    'Title' => $item->Title,
    'Description' => $item->Description,
    'DisplayUrl' => $item->DisplayUrl,
    'Url' => $item->Url,
);
if (in_array($rss_item[$item->Title], $rss_array, TRUE)) {
    return false;
} else {
    array_push($desArray, $item->Description);
    array_push($rss_array, $rss_item);
}
}

/* FREE */
if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
$rawkeyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$keyword = str_replace(' ', '%20', $rawkeyword);
echo $keyword . '<br>';
} else {
echo 'Wrong!';
}
$rootkiri = 'http://www.faroo.com/api?q=';
$key_free = '&key=AAAAAA';
$rootkanan = '&start=1&length=3&l=en&src=web&f=json';
$req = $rootkiri . $keyword . $rootkanan . $key_free;

$ch_free = curl_init($req);
curl_setopt($ch_free, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch_free, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch_free, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch_free, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp_free = curl_exec($ch_free);
$json_free = json_decode($resp_free);
foreach ($json_free->results as $item) {
if (isset($item->kwic)) {
    $rss_item = array(
        'Title' => $item->title,
        'Description' => $item->kwic,
        'Url' => $item->url,
    );
    if (in_array($rss_item[$item->title], $rss_array, TRUE)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        array_push($desArray, $item->kwic);
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
if (in_array($rss_item[$item->title], $rss_array, TRUE)) {
    return false;
} else {
    array_push($rss_array, $rss_item);
}
}

/* DISPLAYING RESULT */
for ($i = 0; $i < count($desArray); $i++) {
    echo '<p>'
    . '<a href="' . $rss_array[$i]['Url'] . '" onclick="return false;">'
    . '<img src="images/positif.png" title="rate this positive" onclick="positif(this);">'
    . '<img src="images/negatif.png" title="rate this negative" onclick="negatif(this);">'
    . $rss_array[$i]['Title']
    . '</a>'
    . '<a href="' . $rss_array [$i]['Url'] . '" target="_blank">'
    . '<img src="images/open_new_tab.jpg" title="open in new tab">'
    . '</a>'
    . '<br/>'
    . '<span class="deskripsi">' . $rss_array [$i]['Description'] . '</span>'
    . '<hr/>'
    . '</p>';
}
?>
```

What I'm asking is the `in_array` thing,
It doesn't work and gives me this:
`Notice: Undefined index:` (followed by the rss_array[title], repeatedly)
Then the results displayed, but the duplicates keep showing up.

I tried to do this:

```
if (in_array($item->title, $rss_array, TRUE)) {
```

It dismisses the notice thing, but still doesn't dismiss the duplicates.
For record, these Google, Bing and Free codes worked very well separately. But when I try to unite the results by removing the duplicates, this "stuckness" happens.
How do I solve this?
Thank you.. :)

Comment: i think your $rss_array is multidimensional (you pushed an array into it) and checked for a string ($item->title) in your in_array(). This couldn't work. Maybe try `in_array($rss_item,$rss_array,TRUE)` but this would only work if the whole $rss_item is the same. Not only the title.

Comment: I don't think that would work cause the description will so much vary.. :(

Comment: So create an title_array with titles only and do the in_array with this array. if it doesnt exists in title array push the rss_item to rss_array and the title to title_array.

Comment: Is it like this: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdv6syekik8sc6e/upload.php)? Still doesn't work though..

Comment: No, please look at my answer... the following is wrong: `array_push($title_array,$item->Title);
    if (in_array($title_array, $rss_array) == TRUE) { ` you should not push the title to titles array each time. Only if in_array is false. and your in_array is wrong, too. Dont match the title_array with rss_array but the title with title_array

Comment: the solution of @KKobayashi is nice, too. In that case you dont need the helper-array. But maybe it is a little bit harder to get what happens there.

Comment: by the way it seems to be a nice thing what you are doing there. Do you want to show us the url of your search engine?

Comment: Steven: Thanks, thanks so much :) I don't really understand how the @KKbobayashi's solution. ^^v Yea I'm doing in my project for my bachelor degree (mini-thesis). I haven't launched it yet. Still getting confused on hosting thing and stuff..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should create a rss_titles helper array like this

```
$rss_array = array();
$rss_titles = array();

foreach(...) {
    if (in_array($item->title, $rss_titles)) {
        //return false;
        continue; // Maybe you dont want to return false but to continue...
    } else {
        // you only need to create $rss_item if the title is not in_array:
        $rss_item = array(
            'Title' => $item->title,
            'Description' => $item->kwic,
            'Url' => $item->url,
        );
        array_push($rss_array, $rss_item);
        array_push($rss_titles, $item->title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is making sure the titles are unique, you should try this

replace

`if (in_array($rss_item[$item->Title], $rss_array, TRUE)) {`

with

`if (in_array($item->Title, array_map(function($e) { return $e['Title']; }, $rss_array))) {`

This fixes 2 problems:

1. `$rss_item[$item->Title]` is probably supposed to be `$rss_item['Title']`, but that's equal to `$item->Title`.
2. You don't want to search `$rss_array` for `$item->Title`, you want to search the 'Title' key of all arrays in `$rss_array` for `$item->Title`, which is what `array_map` does.

More reading:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

You're using incorrect paramaters.

From [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) documentation:

```
If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.
```

I doubt if that's what you want.

Try the following:

```
if (in_array($item->title, $rss_array) == TRUE) {

//code

}
```

Or even:

```
if(in_array($item->title, $rss_array)){
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i think this will not work because $rss_array is not an array of titles. It is an array of arrays with an index named `Title` in each.

Comment: Amal: Thanks but still doesn't work. :((
Steven: yea I think so, still I don't get how to pull up the array inside array to outside array like this.. T.T

Comment: Helps if you post `print_r($post)` output.

Comment: Sorry what does that mean? `$post`?

Comment: `print_r($feed)`, I mean.